# How to trigger dependant task after gulp watch

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I've been trying to figure out how to trigger a dependant task after a task which uses [`gulp-watch`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-watch). I guess I'm doing something bad here. So, what I want to do is to transpile whole project (+ watch the changes) and after that's done I want to trigger a bundling task that is dependant on this one. Since task of transpiling has watching included, I can't put it as dependant task, but I need a way to know when whole transpiling has been done, to do the initial bundling and on each change I want to do the bundle again.

How to do this?

This is how the transpilation task looks like:

```
gulp.task('babel', () => {
  return gulp.src(babelSrc)
    .pipe(watch(babelSrc, () => console.log('watch'))
    .pipe(babel({...}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
});
```

Callback passed to watch will console log `watch` everytime a file has been transpiled, which I can use only after to trigger bundling task only after initial transpilation of the whole project has been done.

Answer (score 0):

> what I want to do is to transpile whole project [...] and after that's done I want to trigger a bundling task

That's not possible the way you're doing it now. When you `.pipe()` the `gulp-watch` plugin it prevents the stream from emitting the `'end'` and `'finish'` events. So there's no way to know when the initial `babel` compilation has finished.

You need to separate the initial compilation from the watch.
That way you can listen for the `'end'` event and trigger your dependent task from there.

```
gulp.task('dependend-task', () => {
  ...
});

function babelStream(stream) {
  return stream
   .pipe(babel({...}))
   .pipe(gulp.dest('build'))
   .on('end', () => gulp.start('dependend-task'));
}

gulp.task('babel', () => {
  watch(babelSrc, {ignoreIntial:true, read:false}, function(file) {
    return babelStream(gulp.src(file.path));
  });
  return babelStream(gulp.src(babelSrc));
});
```